# DataStax C# driver released versions

Tags: cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

I see that [DataStax C# driver v3.17](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-879) has an improvement we would like to use, but the [C# driver page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.16/) shows 3.16 as the latest version. However, the [GitHub changes page](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) shows versions up to 3.19.1, with dates I assume to be release dates.

Is the DataStax site page outdated, and can we consider 3.17 as "released"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's up with the DataStax C# driver page, but you're right.  That's not up-to-date.  Let me bring that to the attention of our docs team.

Yes, 3.17 has been released.  The current version of the DataStax C# driver is indeed 3.19.1, and it looks like it was released about 2 months ago.